# Get selector used to init plugin within plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins, selector

How to get the selector used to initialise a plugin within the plugin?

My first idea was to use `$(this).attr('class');` but that would retrieve all classes set.

**edit**

$('.thisSelector').pluginName();

How can I retrieve this selector within the plugin?

Comment: didn't get your question properly

Answer (score 4):

`$(this).selector` see [api docs](http://api.jquery.com/selector/)

Comment: again, if i was to use this but the selector used was $('.ex1, .ex2').plugin(); with element <a class="ex2"></a> it would return '.ex1, .ex2' not ex2...

Comment: @Phil Jackson How do you expect that this would magically happen, can you explain why you need this and maybe here is a better way around your issue!

Comment: [*"The .selector property was deprecated in jQuery 1.7"*](http://api.jquery.com/selector/).

Comment: @Pang answer was in 2011 when selector was avail

Answer (score 0):

Actually, within a plugin, there is no need to wrap "this" in a jQuery function, so it's just

```
this.selector
```

Sorry I don't have enough reputation to add this as a comment.